# Which RedHat version is supported Fredhopper 7.5.2?

Tags: smarttarget

I will install SmartTarget 2014 SP1 with Fredhopper 7.5.2, and i want know wich RedHat version is supported  Fredhopper 7.5.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fredhopper's OS requirements for Linux are:

> Linux kernel 2.6+ glibc 2.3.5+ (fedora 2.3.5-10.3+) compiled for 64bit (e.g. Suse10+)

From: https://www.fredhopper.com/learningcenter/display/learningcenter/Fredhopper+Installation+Requirements#FredhopperInstallationRequirements-OperatingSystem

Comment: And for RedHat?

Comment: Any version of RedHat that uses Linux Kernel 2.6 or higher - https://access.redhat.com/articles/3078